# CSS different border widths overlapping themselves

Tags: css, border

I'm having trouble with borders overlapping themselves because of the different width the border-top has.

Here is an example code of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/u7KhX/

```
.border{ width: 200px; height: 200px; border-top:5px solid #894b9d; border-right: 1px solid #dad9d9; border-bottom: 1px solid #dad9d9; border-left: 1px solid #dad9d9;
```

As you can see the purple part is not complete.

Any Ideas?

Comment: But if the purple part was complete, the thin grey ones wouldn't have been!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the top border a perfect rectangle and still have the other borders the way you want them by using the div's `::after` pseudo element.

Put the top border on the div itself and the other three borders on the pseudo-element.

For example:

```css
.border {
    width: 200px; height: 200px; border-top:5px solid #894b9d;
    padding: 0 1px 1px 1px;
    position:relative;
}
.border::after {
    display:block; content:'';
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    width:200px; height:200px;
    border-color:#dad9d9; border-style:solid; border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/u7KhX/9/).

Edit:
Or if you don't want to rely on a given width and height, like this:

```css
.border {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding:.5em;
    border-top:5px solid #894b9d;
}
.border::after {
    display:block; content:'';
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-color:#dad9d9; border-style:solid; border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

I've made it an inline-block, to show that it works fine with dynamic content sizes, but you can work with all kinds of widths.

[more updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/u7KhX/11/).

Comment: It's only working with width and height declared, my divs will never have the same height nor width, I need it to work with every div I have. :/

Answer (score 0):

The spec is pretty vague about this, but all browsers implement it the same way:

Wherever 2 borders meet, there will always be an abrupt diagonal line.

---

This has been put to good use, by making triangle & other shapes in pure CSS. Check out this gallery:

[**The shapes of CSS**](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), by Chris Coyer.